# How to ignore .phpt files in Netbeans 10?

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

Netbeans is showing errors for `.phpt` files.

How can I prevent Netbeans from doing this?

[image]

Comment: Lemme know if it didn't answer your question.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I've been trying to put `.phpt` there. Doesn't seem to work. E.g., `^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(phpt|git|hg|svn|cache|DS_Store)$|^Thumbs.db$`

Comment: Try using `*.phpt` and tell me.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Doesn't work but I played around and this works: Add `|.phpt` at the end of the string. I now ignore the whole `phpunit` folder because some files other than `.phpt` also show errors. I now have `|phpunit` at the end of the string.